# can't find android AutoCompleteTextView element

Tags: android, mobile, automated-tests, appium, uiautomatorviewer

I can't access the marked X element.

Already talked with the developers and they said it is not possible to put an id or accessibility tag on it, they say is this element type https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.

I'd do it through x and y position but then it breaks on different devices with different resolutions if I use hardcoded numbers.

How can I locate this element more effectively?

I'm using appium for test automation but this must be a problem for any test automation framework.

The tool used in the image is uiautomatorviewer.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views

Comment: @Angusiasty what's that?

Comment: @Angusiasty I added more detail to the question, it seems is not a custom view

Answer (score 1):

You can do with X & Y position without hardcode the value and it will work other devices also, since "X" button doesn't have locator its inbuilt functionality with edittext, so android uiautomator won't have access on this element

1. Get the Length of the EditText
2. Get the X & Y
3. Pass value in Touch action with (3/4 of X, Y/2)

This will click on that position, here you need to change the 3/4 according to your position

Comment: need to check how I can split the x position in order to work on all resolutions.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the class of the element.
`driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));`

if appears more than 1 elemnts you could try with 
`List<WebElement> e=driver.findElements(By.className("GLButton"));
        e.get(≤Position>).click();`

Comment: I tried, only get that 1 element, which has the whole rectangle, doesn't return the X

Answer (score -1):

You can use Touchaction class to tap on the Cross option in the editText field.

Try using the below code

```
// Identify the x and y co-ordinate for EditText field
    Point elementLoc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of edittext field")).getLocation();
    int eleX = elementLoc.getX();
    int eleY = elementLoc.getY();

// Identify the width and height of the editText field
    Dimension elementDimen = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of edittext field")).getSize();
    int eleH = elementDimen.getHeight();
    int eleW = elementDimen.getWidth();


// Determine the x and y co-ordinates of cross option    
    int touchX = (int)(eleX + eleW * 0.75D); // 75% from the x co-ordinate of editText field ( x axis position for cross option)
    int touchY = (int)(eleY + eleH * 0.5D);  // 50 % from the y co-ordinate of editText field (y axis position for cross option)

// Tap on the cross option
    TouchAction<?> action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action.tap(PointOption.point(touchX, touchY)).release().perform();
```

**Experiment with the offset value for touchX and touchY variable before finding the exact position of cross option.**

Comment: I clearly said on the description  
```I'd do it through x and y position but then it breaks on different devices with different resolutions if I use hardcoded numbers.```

my problem is that there is no `"xpath of edittext field"`  for the element....